# Compiling ROS2 from source on RPI5 with Ubuntu 23.10

Tags: ros2, raspberry-pi

I have setup an LXD instance with ubuntu 23.10, and tried to compile ros humble from source as described in https://docs.ros.org/en/eloquent/Installation/Linux-Development-Setup.html
and the step:

> rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro humble -y --skip-keys "console_bridge fastcdr fastrtps libopensplice67 libopensplice69 rti-connext-dds-5.3.1 urdfdom_headers"

I get the error:

> ignition_math6_vendor: No definition of [ignition-math6] for OS version [mantic]
> ignition_cmake2_vendor: No definition of [ignition-cmake2] for OS version [mantic]
> rti_connext_dds_cmake_module: No definition of [rti-connext-dds-6.0.1] for OS version [mantic]

Is there any way to avoid these dependencies? I am sure ignition library could be eliminated, however rti_connext_dds_cmake_module woud needed to be ported.

If anyone interested, we can make a group with a purpose to compile ros2 humble/iron from source on the RPI5.

Any ideas/recomendations/help greatly appreciated.

Best Regards,
C.